# Android button onclicklistener animation is not working

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I am working on android app and my animation is not working when I am clicking on button.

Here my codes,

```
//Login layout signup button click listener to hide login layout and show signup layout
        loginUserSignupBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivityActionFadeInAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    signupDetailsLayout.startAnimation(startActivityActionSlideUpAnim);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            startActivityActionFadeOutAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    loginDetailsLayout.setAnimation(startActivityActionSlideDownAnim);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    try {

                        Thread.sleep(200);

                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        //We are doing nothing here
                        System.out.println(e.toString());
                    }
                    finally {
                        signupDetailsLayout.startAnimation(startActivityActionFadeInAnim);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat (Animation animation){

                }
            });


            loginDetailsLayout.setAnimation(startActivityActionFadeOutAnim);

            Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Signup clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Toast is working fine, but the animation I am trying is not working.

Here is my xml layout file,

```
 <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/startActivityAppLogoLayout"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true"
     android:padding="5dp"
    >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/startActivityAppLogo"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/startActivityAppLogo"
        android:text="@string/start_activity_app_title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/startActivityAppTitleTV"
        android:textColor="#7f8c8d"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/loginDetailsLayout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userLoginNameET"
        android:ems="12"
        android:hint="@string/login_user_name_edit"
        android:textColor="#1abc9c"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="12"
        android:hint="@string/login_user_pass_et"
        android:id="@+id/userLoginPasswordET"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userLoginNameET"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#1abc9c"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_user_login_btn"
        android:id="@+id/userLoginButtonLogin"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#D24D57"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userLoginPasswordET"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userLoginPasswordET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/userLoginPasswordET"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="@string/login_user_forgot_tv"
        android:layout_below="@id/userLoginButtonLogin"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/userLoginForgotTV"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_user_signup_btn"
        android:id="@+id/userLoginButtonSignup"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#c0392b"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userLoginPasswordET"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/userLoginPasswordET"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/userLoginPasswordET"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/signupDetailsLayout"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/userSignupNameET"
        android:ems="12"
        android:hint="@string/signup_user_name_edit"
        android:textColor="#1abc9c"
        />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="12"
        android:id="@+id/userSignupEmailET"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="@string/signup_user_email_et"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userSignupNameET"
        android:textColor="#1abc9c"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:ems="12"
        android:hint="@string/login_user_pass_et"
        android:id="@+id/userSignupPasswordET"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userSignupEmailET"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#1abc9c"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="12"
        android:id="@+id/userSignupPhoneET"
        android:hint="@string/signup_user_mobile_et"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userSignupPasswordET"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="#1abc9c"/>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_user_login_btn"
        android:id="@+id/userSignupButtonLogin"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#c0392b"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userSignupPhoneET"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/userSignupPhoneET"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/userSignupPhoneET"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:text="@string/signup_user_terms_tv"
        android:layout_below="@id/userSignupButtonLogin"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:id="@+id/userSignupTermsTV"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_user_signup_btn"
        android:id="@+id/userSignupButtonSignup"
        style="?android:buttonBarButtonStyle"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="#D24D57"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userSignupPhoneET"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/userSignupPhoneET"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/userSignupPhoneET"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also tried creating a function but it didn't work either and codes are,

```
//Login layout signup button click listener to hide login layout and show signup layout
        loginUserSignupBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                activateLayoutAnimation(signupDetailsLayout, loginDetailsLayout);
                //Toast.makeText(StartActivity.this, "Signup clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

and function is,

```
//For action layout animations
    private void  activateLayoutAnimation(final RelativeLayout showLayout, final RelativeLayout hideLayout){


        startActivityActionFadeInAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                showLayout.startAnimation(startActivityActionSlideUpAnim);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });

        startActivityActionFadeOutAnim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                hideLayout.setAnimation(startActivityActionSlideDownAnim);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(200);

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //We are doing nothing here
                    System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
                finally {
                    showLayout.startAnimation(startActivityActionFadeInAnim);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat (Animation animation){

            }
        });


        hideLayout.setAnimation(startActivityActionFadeOutAnim);


    }
```

Thank you for your time and help friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setAnimation does not immediately start the animation.  To immediately start, call startAnimation instead.

Comment: Thanx for helping me, its kind of working, all i need now is to hack lil bit more into codes to make them work properly. ;) Thank you very much.